# Emulating c++ 'using namespace' via _ENV

Tags: lua, metatable, lua-5.2, meta-method, lua-5.3

if I have a file `foo.lua`:

```
local foo = {}
foo.add = function(a, b) return a+b end
foo.sub = function(a, b) return a-b end
foo.multiply = function(a, b) return a*b end
return foo
```

and in `bar.lua` I make heavy use of code from `foo.lua` I am bothered by typing `foo.add()` all the time and would prefer to write just `add()` in `bar.lua` I can add this:

```
local foo = require('foo')
local add, sub, multiply = foo.add, foo.sub, foo.multiply
```

but that begins to be a pain when you are including aliasing many values from many files. In c++ there is a way around this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std
```

In lua I was thinking you could emulate this feature like so:

```
local foo = require('foo')
setmetatable(_ENV, {__index = foo})
```

<s>from what I can tell it respects scope so thing like the code below play nice:</s>

actually the code below does not work. I was running the code through the lua repl. When I wrote the code snippet below in a lua file it did not have give the desired result.

```
f = function() -- returns 2
    setmetatable(_ENV, {__index = foo})
    return add(1, 1)
end 
add(1, 1) -- returns 2
```

is there any reason I might regret doing this? (other than reasons that also appy to `using namespace`)

Comment: Using C++ in such a manner is increasingly being considered poor practice.

Comment: I know the slew of reasons it's unpopular in c++ and I'm not, going to after getting a response to this thread start putting this all over my lua code. I tend to avoid writing code that requires advanced knowledge to understand where possible because it makes the code less readable, and this clearly violates that rule. I was just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the global environment is not polite to other libraries.

Try the other way around:

```
do
  local _ENV = setmetatable(foo, {index = _ENV})
  print(add(1, 1))
end
```

Note that `add` will be resolved in `foo` and `print` in the original `_ENV`.